# Updating progressbar external class

Tags: c#

Basically, I have a class and inside it a function which counts all lines within a text file.

I need it to update the progress bar from Form1 with each line it counts. I have tried:

```
public static void rfile(string f)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(f);
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    foreach (string l in lines)
    {
        form.increaseProg();
    }
}
```

---

Form.cs

```
public void increaseProg()
{
    progressBar.Value++;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    progressBar.Refresh();
}
```

But that doesn't seem to increase the progress bar at all.

Comment: Make the Class raise a Custom Event that the Form subscribes to.  Otherwise, you need to pass a reference to the Form into the Class when you create it so you are updating the actual Form that is displayed on the screen.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm not too sure what you mean. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the `Progress` class to make updating the UI during a long running operation easy on everyone involved.  Create the `Progress` class within your form, and indicate how it should update the UI when it is given progress.  Then give that object to the other class that is going to be doing the long running work:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += (p, value) => progressbar1.Value = value;
    Task.Run(() => SomeOtherClass.DoWork("c:/temp.txt", progress));
}
```

The long running work is of course done in another thread to avoid blocking the UI.  The `Progress` class will take care of marshaling the `ProgressChanged` event to the UI thread for us, so we don't need to think about it.

Now for the worker we just need to report progress when needed:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public static void DoWork(string filepath, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        int currentProgress = 0;
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filepath))
        {
            DoSomethingWithLine();
            currentProgress++;
            progress.Report(currentProgress);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that another advantage of this approach is that `SomeOtherClass` doesn't need to know anything about the form.  It can be called by anyone that can provide an `IProgress` object.  If you have some other form needing to call that method you don't need to change it at all.  It also means that if one developer is writing the form and another is coding the long running process they only need to agree on the signature of the `DoWork` method; and from then on the UI guy and do all of the UI work and the non-UI guy can do all of the non-UI work, and they don't need to worry about what the other person is doing.

As for why your code isn't working, the problem is that your worker method isn't accessing the instance of the form that is being displayed, you're creating a brand new form, modifying it's progress bar, never showing it to anyone, and then throwing it away.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are reading the lines and when updating the progressbar, the UI won't entirely refresh as you are imagining. What you need to do, as it sometimes can work, is to do a progressBar.Refresh() (I cannot remember if the progressbar has a refresh function) so it can update the form visuals (specifically the progressbar) whilst it is working the way through the lines. basically, its "too fast" which can cause the delay in updating.

The progress bar is updating, you just don't see the refresh happening. One way is to make it multithreaded perhaps but this would be overkill for reading lines and updating the UI.

not only this, your code basically does NOT show the UI... it is updating, and not showing the UI, you need to Show() the form and perform the updates on it. you instantiate the form, but you don't actually show it.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but when I call the class, it calls `public partial class Form1 : Form` which then I assume it recreates the form because of `public Form1()` => `InitializeComponent();`. Am I right in saying that? If I am, what would be another way to work around it?

Comment: Not sure I understand. you create an instance of a form - great. But now.. you aren't showing the form. If you do: form.Show(), it will show the form which has the controls you have placed on the form, including the progress bar

Comment: I can see the progress bar and the actual form fine. I've found out something though. I added that in the loop, and it opened a few forms with 1 value on the progress bar. So it somehow isn't updating. So in the function that is meant to update, I added `progressBar.Value = 100;` but it simply doesn't update on the form itself (the value does). I added `.Refresh()` and still nothing. It is as if it is locked into place while it is open.

Comment: ok, well as I said - this is because its probably going through too fast for it to actually show any update on the form itself. Are you sure you set the Min and Max values on the progress bar too? If you place say, for testing practices and not good for production reasons, Thread.Sleep(1000) - this will sleep for 1 second and you should then be able to see the update. Also place the progress bar Refresh() method call after you do the Thread.Sleep(1000) in your for loop when reading the lines.

Comment: It's still the same. I even added a loop to `increaseProg` to increase it by 1 each second and using Refresh(). Still doesn't show on the form.

Comment: Well, seems something else is wrong. Are you sure you posted the correct FULL code? I can get it to work on mine fine even with the intentional delay.

Comment: I agree that something else is going on. I posted 3 solutions that all work, and your solution works as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => ProgressBar1.Value = value));
```

You can sometimes get away with using the line above to update the UI while doing other work. you'll need some way to keep track of the progress numerically though.

as stated, since you are tying up your main thread with processing, you can't update the UI on the same thread. The above carves out a tiny chunk of time to do this. The only other method would be a background worker, though that is probably overkill for your situation.

**edit (Display on separate form)**
Did you set the modifier on your progressbar to public? This solution works just fine for showing progress in a separate window, and it updates correctly.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.progressBar1.Maximum = 1000;
        f2.Show();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            f2.progressBar1.Value++;
        }
    }
```

Note that the UI of the progress window will be locked until the underlying process completes. I just tested this and it works fine.

**Update progress on same form, but from different class**
You need to pass a reference of the progressbar so your method knows what it is updating.

```
}
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 c = new Class1();
        progressBar1.Maximum = 1000;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            c.IncreaseProgress(progressBar1);
        }
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public void IncreaseProgress(ProgressBar p)
    {
        p.Value++;
    }
}
```

Both of the above methods will lock the UI while updating though. Use a BackgroundWorker to avoid this. This solution works well in quick and dirty utilities though.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Check my comment to the other answer though. Could that be the issue?

Comment: So is your progressbar appearing on a new form, not the form that initially launched the process?

Comment: Nevermind. I think we can rule that out now. I added a check so it doesn't initialize it a second time. It still doesn't update, even with the refresh.

Comment: It's in the same form but different classes. `increaseProg` is in Form1.cs and the loop is in `main.cs`

Comment: Wait, so your calling a Winform from a console application? Why not just write the entire thing in Winforms then?

Comment: fair point @LeeHarrison - however regardless, it shouldn't matter so much as long as the right assemblies are added to the project.

Comment: I agree, I was just kinda struck when I realized that's what was happening. I'd never thought of doing that.

Comment: No, not at all. Basically I have another class file for the winform application `main.cs` which counts each line then calls the `increaseProg` which is meant to increase the bar by one. So like your example would be the other way around. Just the function with the increment part would be called multiple times

Comment: what is the form.progressU() method? Can we see code for that? I think you should just pass a reference of the progressbar to your update method and you'll be good.